# How to loop through millions of Django model objects without getting an out of range or other error

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I have millions of objects in a Postgres database and I need to send data from 200 of them at a time to an API, which will give me additional information (the API can only deal with up to 200 elements at a time). I've tried several strategies. The first strategy ended up with my script getting killed because it used too much memory. This attempt below worked better, but I got the following error: django.db.utils.DataError: bigint out of range. This error happened around when the "start" variable reached 42,000. What is a more efficient way to accomplish this task? Thank you.

```
articles_to_process = Article.objects.all() # This will be in the millions
dois = articles_to_process.values_list('doi', flat=True) # These are IDs of articles

start = 0
end = 200 # The API to which I will send IDs can only return up to 200 records at a time.
number_of_dois = dois.count()
times_to_loop = (number_of_dois / 200) + 1

while times_to_loop > 0:
     times_to_loop = times_to_loop - 1
     chunk = dois[start:end]
     doi_string = ', '.join(chunk)
     start = start + 200
     end = end + 200

     [DO API CALL, GET DATA FOR EACH ARTICLE, SAVE THAT DATA TO ARTICLE]
```

Comment: "bigint out of range" means a value for a bigint-typed column is too large (or too small). Which database are you on?

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [iterator](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#iterator):

```
chunk_size = 200
counter = 0
idx = []
for article_id in dois.iterator(chunk_size):
    counter += 1
    idx.append(str(article_id))
    if counter >= chunk_size:
        doi_string = ', '.join(idx)
        idx = []
        counter = 0
        # DO API CALL, GET DATA FOR EACH ARTICLE, SAVE THAT DATA TO ARTICLE
```

Comment: This won't help with the bigint problem though.

Comment: He is using Postgres, tested with 2000K rows and worked without any errors.

Comment: Thanks. I ended up recasting the queryset as a list and that seemed to work.